# day of the week to day number (Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2)

Tags: php, datetime, date

Does php have a function to automatically convert dates to their day value, where Monday=1, Tuesday=2, etc. Something like this

```
$daynum = func('wednesday'); //echos 3
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

```
$day_of_week = date('N', strtotime('Monday'));
```

Answer (score 22):

The [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function can return this if you specify the format correctly:

```
$daynum = date("w", strtotime("wednesday"));
```

will return 0 for Sunday through to 6 for Saturday.

An alternative format is:

```
$daynum = date("N", strtotime("wednesday"));
```

which will return 1 for Monday through to 7 for Sunday (this is the ISO-8601 represensation).

Comment: ISO-8601 starts weekday with 1=Monday to 7=Sunday (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 16):

What about using idate()? [idate()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.idate.php)

```
$integer = idate('w', $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 13):

```
$day_number = date('N', $date);
```

This will return a 1 for Monday to 7 for Sunday, for the date that is stored in $date. Omitting the second argument will cause date() to return the number for the current day.

Comment: Or better: `$day_number = date('N', strtotime($date));`

Answer (score 3):

```
$tm = localtime($timestamp, TRUE);
$dow = $tm['tm_wday'];
```

Where `$dow` is the day of (the) week. Be aware of the herectic approach of [`localtime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.localtime.php), though (pun): Sunday is not the last day of the week, but the first (0).

Comment: That's not heretical at all. After all, God rested on the 7th day (Saturday) ;-)

Comment: @pst Argh. I should have defined before stating. I always forget that.