# how to compare last week and last month date functions

Tags: php, mysql

```
$start = strtotime('this week');
$results =$wpdb->get_results("SELECT count( doctor_name ) AS totalleads FROM  `wp-leads-count` WHERE doctor_name ='Sasanthi' and leads_date >='". $start."'");
```

this is my code to get last week leads count from table doctor name and where date with in this week (means today is thusday then start from previous week)
it not working??

and have do same for function like last month ??

in my db i use this `leads_date`  field as timestamp

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `date_sub` function from mysql

get all records from last week

`` SELECT count(doctor_name) AS totalleads FROM  `wp-leads-count` WHERE doctor_name ='Sasanthi' and leads_date between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and now() ``

get all records from last month

`` SELECT count(doctor_name) AS totalleads FROM  `wp-leads-count` WHERE doctor_name ='Sasanthi' and leads_date between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and now() ``

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$daynumber = date('N', date('d'));// getting today day number
$prevweek = $daynumber+7; // starting from prev week 
echo $prevdate = strtotime('-'.$prevweek.' days'); // prev week date
echo strtotime("-1 month"); // last month
```

For more :-
[Getting last month's date in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889758/getting-last-months-date-in-php)

[day of the week to day number (Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961793/day-of-the-week-to-day-number-monday-1-tuesday-2)