# How to get day number of the week of current month's first day in PHP

Tags: php, date

I want to get day number of week of the current month. For example

to day

```
Sep. 1st, Monday
```

should return `1`

```
Oct. 1st, Wednesday
```

should return `3`

```
21.11.2014
```

should return `6`

Comment: `date('N', strtotime('First day of '.date('F').' '.date('Y')))`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961793/day-of-the-week-to-day-number-monday-1-tuesday-2

Comment: @Chad it's not duplicate. Your recommend question is for number of week day from a day and this question is no of week in sense of a month from a day.

Comment: @monsur.hoq true, there is ambiguity/distinction in the question, though the solution for the other answer is applicable to both questions. Good catch; worth an up-vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var_dump(date('N', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n'), 1)));
```

It's not clear from your question whether your input is a string or whether the function should assume the current month/year that is right now.

Answer (score 2):

```
$weekdayNumber = date('N', strtotime($datestring));
```

This returns 1:

```
date('N', strtotime('Sep. 1st, Monday'));
```

This returns 3:

```
date('N', strtotime('Oct. 1st, Wednesday'));
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment `date('N', ...)` can be used to achieve this:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

echo date('N', strtotime('First day of month')) . PHP_EOL;
echo date('N', strtotime('Sep. 1st, Monday')) . PHP_EOL;
echo date('N', strtotime('Oct. 1st, Wednesday')) . PHP_EOL;
```

Or see here: http://codepad.org/mr6itbjK

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you actually don't know the weekday ('Monday', 'Wednesday') so all of the following would also work:

```
echo date('N', strtotime('Sep. 1st')); // this assumes "this year"
echo date('N', strtotime('Sep. 1st 2014'));
echo date('N', strtotime('2014-09-01')); 

echo date('N', strtotime('Oct. 1st')); // this assumes "this year"
echo date('N', strtotime('Oct. 1st 2014'));
echo date('N', strtotime('2014-10-01'));
```

see also http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php