# Convert Number to Day of Week

Tags: php, date, time

I need to convert a number to a date ie

```
1 -> Sunday
2 -> Monday
```

I have the following question which aids with the opposite: [day of the week to day number (Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961793/day-of-the-week-to-day-number-monday-1-tuesday-2)

Once I am able to do this I could for example loop through and echo the day ie:

```
while($i < 7)
{
    echo date("N",strtotime(1));
}
```

Everything I am searching for seems to be people asking to convert a day to a number. Can someone please point me in the right direction

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just put the days in an array using the day of the week as the key. Then use [`date('N')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to get the day of the week and use that as they key to access that array value.

```
$days = [
  1 => 'Sunday',
  2 => 'Monday',
  3 => 'Tuesday',
  4 => 'Wednesday',
  5 => 'Thursday',
  6 => 'Friday',
  7 => 'Saturday'
];

echo $days[date('N')];
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I have seen similar to this and was hoping I could avoid having to create an array as I will likely use this multiple times, so i can create a method to return this. Out of interest, there was another answer that has since been deleted. `$dow_text = date('D', strtotime("Sunday +{$dow_numeric} days"));` I wonder if you had any opinion on this method, I ask purely because it's a shorter way, albeit by a few lines.

Comment: Actually I have found the following link: http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/131031-return-day-of-week-from-integer-in-php/. This describes both methods and states the method shown above in your answer is much quicker as apparently `date` and `strtotime` functions can be quite slow.

Comment: It cause problem if day 1 is not a Sunday... try that... :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create an Array to do that, Please check this :

```
$dayOfWeek = array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
echo $dayOfWeek[2]."<br />";
echo $dayOfWeek[8%7];
echo $dayOfWeek[date('N')];
```

Why I write an array like that ? index `0 => "Sunday" and 1 => "Monday" ....` ? Because if it's a day you must todo that, `1 week is 7 day` so the rest you can use `"Modulo / %(in php)"` to convert that.

For example :
If date 1 March 2015 is Sunday so the day 8 must be Monday `because 8 mod 7 is 1 or 8%7 (in php) is 1`. So to convert that you just do this `$dayOfWeek[8%7]` to get the dayOfWeek. :)

For another conditional case you need your logic to do that. If day 1 May 2015 is Friday. Just keep in mind to check the year it was to know the February day count is 28 or 29.

How to check ? please try this :

```
$year = 2015;
$feb = (($year%100)and !($year%4)or !($year%400))+28;
echo $feb;
```

Day in year should like this :

```
$month= array(0,31,$feb,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31);

0=0, 1=January,2=February,....
```

Hope this help you out.. :)