# Integer to day string with TWIG / Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm looking for a solution to write a day as string from an Integer.

I found this to have the current day as a string.

```
{{ 'now' | localizeddate("none", "none", null, null, "EEEE") | capitalize }}
```

Result => `Monday`

But I would like to replace `'now'` by an integer.

`1` for Monday
`2` for Tuesday
`3` for W...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961793/day-of-the-week-to-day-number-monday-1-tuesday-2

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller PHP :

```
$day_number = date('N', strtotime('Monday'));
```

In your TWIG template :

```
{{ day_number | localizeddate("none", "none", null, null, "EEEE") | capitalize }}
```

Comment: Thanks, Yes I already tried this. For example, when I try `{{ 1 | localizeddate("none", "none", null, null, "EEEE") | capitalize }}`it returns Thursday not Monday

Comment: Try `var_dump(date("1"));` if result is "Monday" it means that TWIG need intl extention to be defined (http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/intl.html#the-intl-extension). If result is "Thursday" it means that PHP need intl timezone to be defined in php.ini (http://php.net/manual/fr/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone).